# What order should servers be truned on after system update

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server, windows-server

System admins contacted me with notification they will update some features on physical machine on which my virtual machines with SharePoint BackEnd, FrontEnd and SQL servers are.
I want to check does it matter in what order should my virtual machines go online.

Does it matter if they put SQL primary than secondary (I have two SQLs in AlwaysOn mode) server online or it doesn't matter?

Should there be some order which server should be online first and which last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order does not matter in case of SharePoint. Even if you start SharePoint servers 1st then SQL server, SharePoint will auto connect once SQL server available.

SharePoint has ability to reconnect to SQL server. Any order will work

Comment: Thank you! If I understood you correctly it doesn't matter what SQL server I am putting Online first (I have two SQL servers, primary and secondary. )? They are in AlwaysOn, if that matters something.

Comment: For SQL Always on...make Sure witness server(listener) started 1st then primary or secondary

Comment: Small addition to Waqas comment: SQL-Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups no longer have a "witness server". This term comes from Database-Mirroring. Instead you have configured a "Quorum" in Windows Failover-Cluster. In most 2-node-AG implementations, a FileShare is configured. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/wsfc-quorum-modes-and-voting-configuration-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to satisfy a specific order. SharePoint will automatically reconnect its databases as soon as they become available. Also both SharePoint-Servers will find themselves regardless of their startup-order.

If you are hosted on a SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Group (AG), you shouldn't have to take down your entire SQL-Server environment. You pay a high price  for the High-Availability-Features (Enterprise-License), so you should make use of it!

- Perform Maintenance on your secondary node. Restart the node if nessecary
- Wait for the Availability-Group to be synchronized again. Can be monitored in AlwaysOn Dashboard in SQL-Server Management Studio (SSMS)
- Fail over all databases to the secondary, thus becoming the new primary
- Wait again for your AG to be synchronized again
- Perform maintenance on the remaining node, restart, wait for the AG to become synchronized again. You can (not must) fail back your databases to become your original server as primary.
- The whole process is documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/upgrading-always-on-availability-group-replica-instances), as it might not be that straight-forward in a more complex environment.

Comment: thanks for your time and explanation. I voted your answer.